# Что делать, если вы выявили марионетку?

Tags: поддержка, faq, модерация, марионетки

Недавно мы удалили несколько марионеток активного участника с высокой репутацией. После такого хочется рассмотреть, что делать, если видишь участника, который пытается играть с системой данным образом. В частности:

- Можно ли быть уверенным на 100%, что перед вами марионетка?
- В какой момент марионетка начинает создавать проблемы для сообщества?
- Как модераторам следует поступать, когда они нашли марионетку, которая создает проблемы?
- Что если вы были заблокированы за марионетку, но считаете это несправедливым?

---

<sub>Свободный перевод «[How should sockpuppets be handled on Stack Exchange?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/57682/)»</sub>

Comment: А был ли мальчик?

Comment: Очень своевременный пост. (Ирония, если что.)

Comment: Перевод переводом, но «марионетка» как-то не прижилась на руСО. Для меня более подходящим словом тут было бы «клон».

Comment: @alexolut, Война клоническая начнётся тогда, Оби-lut.

Comment: @alexolut можно как "фиктивные учётные записи", sock puppets в этом контексте переводить. "клон" ассоциацию идентичности вызывает, но sock puppets пытаются этого избежать (дистанцироваться). "Марионетки" технически без контекста правильно, но как-то чересчур драматично звучит. В конкретном случае больше слово shill "подставное лицо" подходит.

Answer (score 14):

### Можно ли быть уверенным на 100%, что передо мной марионетка?

Никогда невозможно быть уверенным на 100%. Вот вы *думаете*, что это марионетка, но на самом деле это мой хороший друг Нениколай, который обожает меня настолько, что поддерживает и согласен со всем, что бы я ни написал, полностью копирует мой стиль письма, пользуется моим же компьютером, когда голосует за вопросы и ответы, или публикует сообщения на сайте, когда я отойду за кофе.

В реальном мире существуют шаблоны поведения, которые кардинально отличаются от случаев использования марионетки. Если у вас есть *настоящий* увлеченный вами друг, ему должно быть предельно понятно, когда стоит остановиться в своем порыве. Не стесняйтесь связаться с командой развития сообщества Stack Exchange, если вы не уверены, правильно ли вы вместе с вашим другом поступаете по отношению к остальным участникам своей «взаимопомощью». У нас есть довольно обширный опыт в этом вопросе и мы будем рады вам помочь.

### В какой момент марионетка начинает создавать проблемы для сообщества?

Используйте следующую простую эвристику «да/нет» для понимания является ли марионетка вредительской: **если ваша вторая учетная запись позволяет вам добиться того, чего основная учетка не позволила бы никогда, либо вас бы за это вовремя остановили — это грубое нарушение**. Несколько примеров:

- Голосование за свои собственные вопросы, ответы и комментарии.
- Ответы на свои вопросы с других учетных записей.
- Многократное голосование с разных учетных записей в чужих сообщениях.
- Поддержка своих аргументов во время обсуждений («+1, Николай прав как всегда, не понимаю, почему остальные до сих пор этого не поняли»).
- Использование конкурсов, чтобы обойти ограничение лимита репутации за день.
- Обход блокировки доступа, ограничения за низкое качество сообщений и других ограничений на публикацию вопросов, ответов и комментариев.

### Как модераторам следует поступать, когда они нашли марионетку, которая создает проблемы?

Все зависит от серьезности злоупотреблений второй учетной записью и понимания ситуации модератором, который столкнулся с марионеткой. Обычно, если это первый случай для данного участника:

- Свяжитесь с участником, используя основную учетную запись и, на усмотрение модератора, отправьте предупреждение на вторую учетную запись или сразу удалите ее, если это явная марионетка.

Для последующих нарушений (или для первого случая, не вызывающего сомнения):

- Заблокируйте основную учетную запись и удалите вторую.

### Что если я был заблокирован за марионетку, но считаю это несправедливым / Я даже не думал, что так нельзя / Это был мой коллега из офиса / Я клянусь, это мой злой брат близнец Нениколай!

Узнайте, как работает это сообщество / поговорите с вашим коллегами в офисе / попросите ваше второе Я не выходить из самого дальнего темного угла, пока вы на этом сайте.

Затем, постарайтесь, чтобы подобного более не происходило. Любой может ошибиться, мы верим в вас и не держим обиды.

#### Вы говорили, что есть исключительные случаи, когда можно завести несколько учетных записей. О чем идет речь?

Некоторые люди за все время участия в жизни сайта действительно имели с десяток «вторых» учетных записей. Такие учетные записи полезны: чтобы исследовать дефекты, которые можно воспроизвести только являясь участником с низкой репутацией, вспомнить, как выглядит сайт, когда у тебя нет репутации. Таким образом, подобные учетные записи создаются с исследовательскими намерениями и пониманием, что в будущем их будет необходимо удалить.

Помните, если вы активны с двух учетных записей, но при этом ни одна из них пока еще не нарушила правила, это не спасет вашу марионетку. Как только модераторы ее выявят, она будет удалена, так как невозможно все время следить за вами, а не сделали ли вы что–нибудь не так.

Comment: Кроме удаления учётки возможно слияние. Почему в ответе речь идёт только об удалении? Значит ли это, что слияние в таких ситуациях никогда не используется?

Comment: "Обычно, если это первый случай для данного участника" Первый случай нарушения правил? Или первый случай использования твинка?

Comment: Первый случай, когда нашли марионетку @Suvitruf.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но в недавнем случае это же была первая его марионетка?

Comment: @Qwertiy На мой взгляд, объединение в основном придумано для учетных записей, созданных случайно, без злого умысла. Мы иногда объединяем, а не удаляем, когда это первый «легкий» случай нарушения.

Comment: В недавнем случае была не одна марионетка, и был явно виден умысел, то есть это не была случайность или недоразумение (не понимание участником правил) или что–либо аналогичное, поэтому мы руководствовались вторым пунктом «Заблокируйте основную учетную запись и удалите вторую.»

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky но я не вижу ни учётки FoggyFinder, ни AtomicAlarm. То есть, удалили и твинка, и основную учётку?

Comment: @Suvitruf, у FF ник с пробелом, ищите лучше :)

Comment: @АндрейNOP ха, а слона то я и не приметил :D

Comment: Год назад один раз попросил друга один плюсик поставить для медной медальки, нас теперь заблокируют? :D

Comment: @PeterSamokhin если придёте с повинной, то нет :D

Comment: _Использование конкурсов, чтобы обойти ограничение лимита репутации за день._ - а как это может помочь? общая же сумма не изменится?

Comment: _Голосование за свои собственные ... комментарии._ - а что не так с голосованием за комментарии? С ответами вопросами - понятно, влияет непосредственно на рейтинг

Comment: @Grundy там же есть баджик за набор голосов по комментариям!

Comment: А откуда взялось правило «Поддержка своих аргументов во время обсуждений»? Это случайно не новое правило? Было ли оно раньше?

Comment: @VladD [Это было написано в 2013 году](https://meta.stackexchange.com/revisions/57685/2). В любом случае, если бы даже это было написано вчера, дата написания не являлось бы поводом для не удаления марионетки. Это не то поведение, которое является честным по отношению к остальным. Согласитесь, вести аргументированную дискуссию с реальным человеком несколько сложно, чем самому с собой, а убедить остальных, кто только читает, введя в заблуждения, на порядок проще.

Comment: Я пытаюсь подсадить коллегу на ruSO, он пока регистрироваться не хочет, говорит, что ему достаточно чтения из гостевого режима. У него богатый опыт русского форумного комьюнити и он опасается стать мальчиком для битья, задавая вопросы. Мне стоит отказаться от своих идей? Пусть "не выходит из самого дальнего темного угла", ведь на этом сайте уже есть один человек из нашей компании?

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky: В абстрактном случае я понимаю ваш аргумент. Но мне кажется, этот пост слишком привязан к конкретному случаю.

Comment: Либо этот ответ слишком небинайсный по отношению к честным shared-ip пользователям, либо в нём торжествует презумпция виновности и море сарказма...

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky "В любом случае, если бы даже это было написано вчера" Закон обратной силы не имеет.

Comment: @Grundy чисто технически, при конкурсе сумма не остается той же. Вопрос с конкурсом получает плюсы от привлеченных конкурсом. Обмен конкурсами на нормальных вопросах (особенно если заранее написан и принят ответ от кого надо) - это отличный способ выжать пару сотнен репутации из ниоткуда.

Comment: @PashaPash, _Вопрос с конкурсом получает плюсы от привлеченных конкурсом._ либо минусы

Comment: @vp_arth Пожалуйста, посмотрите как работает модель клиент–сервер и TCP/IP, в том числе [NAT](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/NAT). К этому всему, когда используется прокси для компании с нее сидят огромное количество разработчиков (помните, мы смотрим данные и для нашего сообщества и для англоязычного). Если на одном IP находится две рассматриваемых учетных записи (и только они) в течении очень длительного времени, то это настораживает. Учтите, система отслеживает огромное количество параметров, а не только сам факт одинакового IP.

Comment: @Grundy  да,  но для генерации репутации можно использовать вопросы с +2-3, такое мало кто будет минусовать. Попробуйте конкурс объявить на вопрос недельной давности - увидите

Comment: Огромную роль в определении второй учетной записи играет психология и известные нам шаблоны поведения реальных людей в противовес случаям попыток надуть систему и других участников сообщества марионеткой.

Comment: @NicolasChabanovsky, в нашей компании(офисе) работает 15 человек включая директора. У нас есть 3 обычных белых IP, один из которых является шлюзом. В вашем комментарии лишнее всё, кроме последнего предложения. Be nice, please.

Comment: @vp_arth  совпадения по одному IP -  не подозрительно.  Совпадения по нескольким IP +  периодам их использования + смежная активность (совместные действия) - уже подозрительно. Вы же не станете с вашим соседом по офису на SO общаться,  вы пойдете вместе кофе пить :)

Comment: @PashaPash _Вы же не станете с вашим соседом по офису на SO общаться, вы пойдете вместе кофе пить_ - ооооочень спорное утверждение :)

Comment: В общем, спасибо. Тогда не буду оставлять своих попыток агитации. А там посмотрим, что получится)

Comment: @vp_arth если есть опасения что вопрос не по формату будет, то предложите помощь: черновик вопроса поправить под правила SO (информативный заголовок, достаточно узкий, не слишком субъективный, по теме (/on-topic), содержит необходимую для ответа информацию (/mcve если применим)—уже лучше многих вопросов будет). /tour можно показать и/или видео из /help

Comment: +1, Николай прав как всегда, не понимаю, почему остальные до сих пор этого не поняли!!!!1111

Если серьезно  - никогда не понимал твинководов. Ловить их непросто там вплоть до ботнета. Что делать если поймал? Не обращать внимания. Если они добиваются уважения таким образом - его не будет для какого-то ноунейма который толком не отметился в обществе.

Comment: в данном случае марионетка подразумевает пересечение в ответах и голосованиях между разными аккаунтами одного и того же человека ? а вдруг у него раздвоение личности , и с одной учётки он дает положительные советы, а с другой отрицательные.