# Бизнес-аккаунт как второй аккаунт участника

Tags: поддержка, профиль-участника

Не нашел в явном виде разрешение использовать дополнительный аккаунт для ответов от лица организации, в которой работает участник.
Собственно в этом и вопрос — это вообще легально (во всех смыслах)?

А также, как предотвратить случайное объединение аккаунтов (например, кто-то, предложил в чате объединение, пока участника не было на сайте).

Ну и в целом, должен ли аккаунт соответствовать конкретному лицу, или нормально, что работа идёт от организации, и аккаунт может быть передан другому работнику.

Comment: А за что минус?

Comment: @VladD haters gona hate. Восполнил баланс плюсом.

Answer (score 8):

1. Запрета на доп. аккаунты в целом нету.
2. Какие-то действия в отношении твинков могут быть предприняты, если они используются для:

   1. Накручивания репы.
   2. Обхода бана другого аккаунта.
   3. Других действий, запрещённых правилами.

Далеко ходить не надо, есть вот такой пользователь: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/220220/kagg-design

Требование, разве что, одно (если не брать в расчёт все базовые правила) стоит выделить — нельзя тупо пиарить свой продукт, пихая в каждый ответ ссылку на свой продукт/компанию.

У модераторов есть [гайдлайн для выявления сокпупетов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/57685/260198).

Наш перевод: [Что делать, если вы выявили марионетку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7269/15479)

Не делайте того, за что они могут наказать, и все будут довольны.

Comment: А против случайных объединений учеток что-то можно сделать?

Comment: Ну и в целом, должен ли аккаунт соответствовать конкретному лицу, или нормально, что работа идет от организации, и аккаунт может быть передан другому работнику.

Comment: Добавил в вопрос

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan я думаю, Николас объединяет без уведомления только явных твинков. В сложных случаях он, скорей всего, связывается с людьми. Но можете на всякий случай в описании профиля дописать инфу про аккаунт компании.

Comment: @VladimirGamalyan хорошо бы, конечно, чтоб Николас сам на это ответил.

Answer (score 4):

Слишком поздно, но похоже, учетные записи организаций не разрешены:

https://stackoverflow.com/legal/terms-of-service#obligations

> User Obligations
>
> To access some of the public Network features you will need to register for an account **as an individual** and consent to these Public Network Terms...

"individual" в английском, насколько я знаю, означает именно человека/физическое лицо (юридическое лицо называется "legal entity"). Так что учетная запись не может принадлежать организации.

Comment: Тут скорее имеется в виду, что аккаунт должен принадлежать одному человеку, а не группе людей. На метамете было обсуждение про класс студентов или что-то в этом духе. Если у одного человека есть личный аккаунт и аккаунт организации, то скорее всего этому правилу это не противоречит (хотя может противоречить какому-то другому). Кстати, весьма вероятно, что с появлением команд у многих их участников должен был появиться второй аккаунт с корпоративной почтой - вряд ли работодатель будет приглашать по личному email'у.