# Лайканье анонимных вопросов

Tags: обсуждение, голоса-за, голосование, марионетки

Иногда, я захожу в режим инкогнито и задаю анонимный вопрос при этом не совершая до конца регистрацию → профиль в конечном итоге выпиливается → личной какой-либо выгоды нету.

Собственно, вопрос:

Разрешено ли лайкать (скромный +1) с **основного** профиля собственный же, но **анонимный** вопрос?

Answer (score 6):

- [Что делать, если вы выявили марионетку?](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/7269/260198)
- [What's the policy about having multiple user accounts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/35593/260198)

Вообще, интересно, как правило под запрет подпадает, если что-то делаешь твинком для выгоды основного акка, но про обратную ситуацию ничего внятного не вижу по этой теме.

Но да, главный вопрос: зачем?

Comment: Ну можно защитить вопрос от какого-то минусатора сделав заранее +1 или выделить вопрос в общем потоке вопросов, показав что там что-то интересное, раз стоит +1.

Comment: @iluxa1810 хороший вопрос вряд ли в минусах будет сидеть. А +1 на вопрос твинку - это как раз пример того самого нечестного преимущество, которое может стать причиной бана.

Comment: @iluxa1810 `Ну можно защитить вопрос от какого-то минусатора сделав заранее +1` - чем это от накрутки голосов отличается?

Comment: @tym32167, ну накручивают голоса обычно на основном профиле, что бы получить доступ к большему функционалу платформы и как правило лайканье идет более 1 раза. Тут же по сути +1 уходит в некуда.

Comment: @iluxa1810 не "в никуда", а на получение тактического преимущество. А это тоже нарушение.

Comment: @PavelMayorov ок, понял.

Comment: Для защиты от автоматического удаление ещё может быть нужен +1 - при нуле пустой вопрос через полгода удаляется.

Answer (score 5):

Насколько я понимаю, **запрещены любые действия, позволяющие обойти ограничения, которые имели бы место в случае объединения учётных записей**.

Ваш случай с голосованием однозначно подпадает под такое ограничение, так как за свои сообщения голосовать система не позволяет, независимо от имеющегося кол-ва репутации.

При этом могут быть и менее очевидные ситуации, например, имеется суточное ограничение по кол-ву голосов, и если с разных аккаунтов голосовать за разные же сообщения, но в общей сложности проголосовать больше раз, чем позволяет наиболее «прокачанная» учётная запись, то такое поведение тоже будет рассматриваться как нарушение.